# Filters are not getting reset after loading new data to grid based on selected date

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid

I'm using the date field as a selection criteria for populating the grid.
I want to reset the previously applied filters once the new data is about to be loaded in grid.
However, the filters are not getting removed and the menu icon for filter is showing additional values under select boxes which is very confusing in case the grid has less number of rows. I'm using this in my angularjs website.
Please assist me in getting this resolved.

I've already opened the issue in github also. Below is the link:
https://github.com/ceolter/ag-grid/issues/606

Comment: Any news about this ? Your issues has beend closed on the github